# Xcode Project editor: dropdown lists became input texts (using Xcode 4.4.1)

Tags: osx-lion, xcode4.4

I'm trying to figure out why dropdown lists became input texts in all editable fields of Xcode Project editor (I'm using Xcode 4.4.1 on Lion 10.7.4).

This problem is affecting all the project I create and it is persisting even after uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode.
The same projects opened in other computers are ok.

For example, iOS Deployment Target selection is now a simple input text, not a dropdown list.

This problem is quite annoying especially because it makes really hard setting the code signing configurations.

Comment: just found the solution: editor > show values (it was selected editor > show definitions)